# If else condition inside JSP <x:select tag >

Tags: javascript, jsp, if-statement

I want to assign a value to one tag (let's say `TAG1`) in jsp if the value of one variable is empty (let's say the variable is `var1`), and assign blank if `var1` is not empty. I have written code but it's not working.

Below is my code:

```
<x:select id="foldeName" TAG1=${var1 ='' ? TAG1='SOME_VALUE' : TAG1=''}>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5764553/andrew-myers - Instead of editting it would be great if you answer this

Comment: anyways i found my solution